# Ground state wave function of Symmetric potentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Why shouldn't the groundstate wavefunction for symmetric potentials vanish at the origin?

Comment: That would mean the particle has zero probability of being at the origin, which seems rather unlikely.

Comment: It's not clear what this question is trying to ask - we might ask well ask back: Why should it?

Comment: It actually raises an interesting question.  Can someone prove that ground state of a particle in a one symmetric dimensional is symmetric instead of antisymmetric?  I feel that it should be, but can't prove it.

Comment: ["The variational principle is used to show that the ground-state wave function of a one-body
Schro¨dinger equation with a real potential is real, does not change sign, and is nondegenerate"](http://web.salleurl.edu/~mazzanti/papers/variatAJP.pdf) As the references in this paper indicate, this is long known. It think you will find it in Reed and Simon.

Answer (score 3):

For a symmetric potential (in 1D at least), even if you have an even function as the ground state solution, the fact that it is even says nothing about the value it should take at the origin. An even function is defined as one that satisfies
$$f(-x)=f(x)$$
so for $x=0$ this says nothing non-trivial.
If the wave-function is non-zero elsewhere than the origin, then if it *is* zero at the origin it must have turning points elsewhere, and will be more "wiggly" as a function. Roughly speaking, the more wiggly a wave-function the more kinetic energy that system will have, so the ground state is unlikely to have many wiggles!